# Django REST Framework's APIClient sends None as 'None'

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

In my tests, I send mock data of models that I've passed through the serializer. The `serializer.data` looks something like this

```
{
    "field": None
}
```

However, the data that my API receives is formatted like

```
{
    "field": "None"
}
```

which is a problem because I'm trying to specify a foreign key that is allowed to be null. Shouldn't the `APIClient` convert None into null instead of unicode?

Is there any way to fix this or get around it?

Here's my serializer

```
class MyModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    field = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        queryset=OtherModel.objects.all(), required=False, allow_null=True)
```

And my create method in a viewset

```
def create(self, request):
    model = MyModel()
    serializer = MyModelSerializer(model, data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save(owner=request.user)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=201)
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=406)
```

Also my model class

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    field= models.OneToOneField(
        OtherModel, blank=True, null=True)
```

Comment: Can you provide the full serializer and view? Also remember that the django built-in JsonResponse can be used if necessary.

Comment: They're huge files, and for work, but I can put a dumbed down version

Comment: The problem that I'm getting is when deserializing, the serializer expects a PK value for `field` and is getting a unicode "None". I've traced this back to the APIClient, because when I serialize the data `serializer.data` is regular Python None.

Comment: Can you give us your test? It is possible that if you don't send a specified format such as `format='json'` with the request or you are not actually using the `APITestCase` and using the built in client to send the request, errors like this may happen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that the `APIClient` is sending data to the view as form-data by default, which doesn't have a concept of `None` or `null`, so it is converted to the unicode string `None`.

The good news is that Django REST framework will [coerce a blank string to `None`](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/6651432d59ea21999fb48ef526c16242f50317f6/rest_framework/relations.py#L77-L81) for relational fields for this very reason. Alternatively, you can use JSON and actually send `None` or `null`, which should work without issues.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to what Kevin already said, you can force the APIClient to send JSON using the parameter `format='json'`.

See the [documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/testing/#making-requests).

Answer (score 4):

In addition to existing answers, 
if you are expecting a null, this probably means you expect your api to receive json.

If that's the case, you may want to configure the test request default format to json instead of form-data:

In your setting.py:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    ...
    'TEST_REQUEST_DEFAULT_FORMAT': 'json'
}
```

This way, no need to add `format='json'` to each request